# Неполадки при работе с базой данных

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, iis

Проблема следующая. Есть два класса выполняющий обновление резюме пользователя. Для получения резюме использую репозиторий для которого выполняю Get и получаю резюме пользователя по его Id. Оба класса инициализируются через autofac. В класса A при доступе к репозиторию все ок, резюме получаю. А в классе Б возникает исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто знает как быть подскажите в какую сторон копать пожалуйста.

Прикрепляю дополнительные сведения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сведениях об исключении: **error CS0103: Имя "$exception" не существует в текущем контексте.**

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, поле "Дополнительные сведения" полностью. Возможно, стоит посмотреть InnerException

Comment: У вас в `AutoFac` точно все нужные зависимости зарегистрированы?

Comment: Это может быть, если он неправильно устанавливает зависимости?

Comment: Так у вас в исключении всё написано — не зареференсена сборка `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0` добавьте ссылку на сборку.

Comment: Я просто делаю предположение, на основании этого `Оба класса инициализируются через autofac. В класса A при доступе к репозиторию все ок, резюме получаю. А в классе Б возникает исключение.`. На самом деле у вас слишком мало по существу информации. Покажите, что у вас в конструкторе ваших классов `A`  и `B`.

Comment: Вы пробовали это? Посмотрите предупреждения в output при билде. Там пишут про библиотеки, которые прямо не ссылаются проектом, но, на которые ссылаются другие библиотеки. Затем можно попробовать Consolidate packages в "Manage Nuget Packages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге помогло следующее: скачал пакет дополнительных компонентов для SQL Server 2012 R2 SP3, установил. Затем, пересобрал проект и все рабоатет.
Скачал не весь пакет, а только отдельный файл - SqlSysClrTypes.msi. Ставить его нужно для той архитектуры, на которой билдите проект.